# Uncaught ReferenceError: setValue is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class='row' id='dadasd' style='padding-top:10px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;background-color:black;border:2px solid lightgrey;' onclick='setValue()'>
<span title='Edit' style= 'cursor: pointer;font-size:8px;text-align:center;color:lightblue;' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#addWidgetModal'>Edit
</span>
<!-- endadasd -->
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function setValue() {
window.columnId = 'dadasd';
window.outerRowId = 'dadasd';
console.log(window.columnId,window.outerRowId);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code..where the class row when clicked gives an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: setValue is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick  onclick@home:1".
Could anybody please help to find out the error?

Comment: I tried this. There is no error.

Comment: But i am still getting an error..I dont know why!

Comment: copy this exact code in a new html file , dont write anything else.. and try then @SaswatPatro

Comment: Why your browser would add onclick@home:1? You should add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class='row' id='dadasd'  onclick='setValue()'>
<span class="span" title='Edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#addWidgetModal'>Edit
</span>
</div>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function setValue() {
       window.columnId = 'dadasd';
       window.outerRowId = 'dadasd';
       console.log(window.columnId,window.outerRowId);  
      }
</script>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.row {
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  background-color:black;
  border:2px solid lightgrey;
}

.span {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size:8px;
  text-align:center;
  color:lightblue;
}
```

Note: Whenever you developing any application please maintain the code alignment and differentiate the code as per language so easily modify the code and maintain that code for future changes, Well structure code helps you to understand and modify code

[This is Codepen Link If you do not understand then check it on codepen](https://codepen.io/jadhavakshay/pen/qBOwrwJ)